# My suffix is used for cutting, My prefix is used for a house

Tags: riddle

My suffix is used for cutting,
My prefix is used for a house.
One can use this to make music,
Or use it with a mouse.

What am I?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Keyboard

My suffix is used for cutting,

> **Board**, like a chopping board

My prefix is used for a house.

> **Key**, to access the front door

One can use this to make music,

> Piano keyboard

Or use it with a mouse.

> Keyboard on a computer (computer mouse)

Comment: Nice job hexomino!